# python calling empty list invalid syntax

Tags: python

I am trying to create an empty list and for some reason it is telling me it's invalid syntax? it also flags the next line with the same error, saying that while count<amount: is invalid. am i wrong for thinking this doesnt make sense? using vsc. thanks in advance.
my code looks like this.

```
list=[]
count=0
while count < amount :
   s=int(input"enter a number:")
   list.append(s) 
   count= count+1
```

i tried to use list={}, list=() even though i know those are wrong. it also flags lines like list4=[1,3] ??

Comment: `list` is a python reserved word, you can't use it as a variable name

Comment: thanks, ive also tried using random words and it seems like the function itself just isn't working

Comment: can you share the error traceback?

Comment: Can you share the error log?

Comment: there is a `(` missing after `input`

Comment: This is wrong too: `s=int(input"enter a number:")`, it should be `s=int(input("enter a number:"))`

Comment: Yes, there is a syntax error in `s=int(input("enter anumber"))` and define the amount variable

Comment: andrej0 thank youuuuuu no wonder it couldnt move on to the next line. this site is awesome lol it actually works?!?!

Comment: @HuLuViCa, sure you can: `list = []`. It just shadows the built-in so it's not a very good idea.

Answer (score 2):

`amount` is not defined. Define it with a number like 5 and try then.

You also need to make sure the variable `list` is called something else, it is a python-reserved word.

Lastly, make sure the `input` function has parenthesis `()` around it. e.x. `input("enter number: ")`

Answer (score 2):

In python the indent is 4 spaces.

You need to change the variable name "list" because it is a built in name in python.

You need to put brackets after input.

```
amount = 5

numberList = []
count = 0
while count < amount:
    s = int(input("enter a number:"))
    numberList.append(s)
    count += 1
```